# Software to calculate folder size?

Tags: macos

For some reason neither Windows 10 nor MacOS will give me the folder size of a somewhat random folder I was tasked with storing to the cloud.

Is there software I can install, preferably on macOS that will give me the folder size?

Here is the "error" from macOS.  It just stays like that indefenitley.

[image]

Comment: That's not actually an "error" / "Calculating Size - it stays like that indefenitley" - How long is "indefenitley"? "My Passport" - For an external drive that is not _indexed_ by the OS, it can take a considerable time (several hours in extreme cases) to calculate the size, depending on the number and size of the files and interface used. Does Windows 10 not give an indication of progress?

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to check the drive to determine if it has issues that are causing this behavior.  Here is a link to [WD Drive Utilities for Mac](http://downloads.wdc.com/wdapp/WD_Utilities_Standalone_Installer_Mac_2_1_1_100.zip).

If the software reports that everything is okay, then you could do a search for "alternatives to wiztree for mac".  There are many options there.  These programs catalog all the files on a drive and create a report of the size of every folder and sub folder. Or a list of the largest files on the drive, or other options.

The highest rated one appears to be [DaisyDisk](https://alternativeto.net/software/daisydisk/about/).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/) If you're looking for something free. You can see the size of a folder and each of its contents by navigating to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change your mac settings to have the file/folder size displayed.  Click on your desktop and the first menu item, next to the apple icon, is Finder. From this go to the View menu and click on 'Show View Options' near the bottom of the menu pane. See imge below.

[image]

Click on the 'Show View Option' item and you'll get a pane where you can set the 'View Options' on your mac. See 2nd image below.

[image]

On the panel that appears there is a check box near the bottom for 'Calculate All Sizes'. Check this box and folders will display their sizes if you have size selected in the same panel.